# Can I deploy a VHDX image on a physical machine?

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-image, deployment, sysprep

It's been sysprep'd. I want to deploy it on physical machines. I haven't been able to do it so far.

What I tried to do is simply copy the VHDX (I was using Hyper-V VM) (after shutting down the VM after sysprep was done generalizing) image from its folder onto the external HDD of my choice, then plugging it into that laptop along with the USB flash drive containing the Windows.ISO I later booted into, then I chose the System Image Restore option but the system couldn't file any deployable image file

How come? Someone tell me how I can get this to work

Comment: I think the standard way is to capture a WIM image, then work with that.

Comment: The way this is done on my team is to (somehow) copy the actual vhdx image to a drive and set the bcd boot loader to point to it.  I am not the person who does this but I know what they are doing.  You don't "install it" you run right from the vhdx after creating a bcd boot entry.  Like next to 0% performance loss from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are two articles in the Microsoft Docs, which seems to cover scenario:

[Deploy Windows with a VHDX (Native Boot)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-windows-on-a-vhd--native-boot)

and

[Boot to a virtual hard disk: Add a VHDX or VHD to the boot menu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-vhd--native-boot--add-a-virtual-hard-disk-to-the-boot-menu)